# Standard Cartesian Plane

Tags: calculus, functions

I have posted before.

But I had a question,

Is the **standard, ** used cartesian coordinate plane this:

[image]

Where the vertical axis represents $f(x) = y$ and the horizontal axis represents $x$?

I was wondering because in evaluation of

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$

We take:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} dy$$

Then we take $I^2$.

Are you then using $f(y) = e^{-y^2}$ or just changing $x \to y$ ?? So $y$ is the independent variable?

Comment: The vertical axis is the set of points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x=0$. The set of points such that $y=f(x)$ represents a curve in the $xy$ plane. Would it make you feel better if we wrote $$I = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt$$ and $$I = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} e^{- w^2} \, dw?$$ We use $x$ and $y$ because of inertia in switching to polar coordinates. In the example I gave we can write $t = r \cos(\theta), w = r \sin(\theta)$, but for some reason some people aren't comfortable with that and think only $x$ and $y$ can be written in polar coordinates.

Comment: But the problem is, when you **combine** it, when it becomes an iterated integral, then do you have a $3D$ plot of the curve? It becomes $e^{-(t^2 + w^2)}$ but you cant have a $3D$ plot because the nor $w$ nor $t$ are the vertical axis in the 2D graph.

Comment: It's no longer a curve, it becomes a surface.

Comment: Exactly, how? Given: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_coordinate_system_handedness.svg

Then one of the axes **must** be $y$ for example, and one of the axes **must** be $x$ for it to be a 3D system, and a surface.?

Comment: @MarkFantini, do you see? In the 3D plane there is a seperate $xy$ plane, so if we have $e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$ there then the issue would be that either $y$ is a **dependent** variable for $x$ or either $x$ is a **dependent** variable for $y$.

Comment: @MarkFantini, if you do not mind please take a look at the comments here (I wrote): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093322/change-of-freebound-variables-in-integration/1093336?noredirect=1#comment2228979_1093336   and if you will kindly answer the question i asked in the comments

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be looking at is
the usual way to evaluate $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx$
where $f(x)=e^{-x^2}.$
We show that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I^2 &=& \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx\right)
\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y)\;dy\right)\\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) f(y)\;dx\;dy \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y)\;dx\;dy.
\end{eqnarray}$$
That is, instead of doing a single integration of the single-variable
function $f$, we do a double integration of the two-variable function $g$,
where $g(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}.$
Then we change variables to polar coordinates in order to put
the integral in a form that's much easier to evaluate.

While we can make a simple and reasonably complete graph of $y = f(x)$
in the $x,y$-plane consisting of one or more simple curves
that pass the "vertical line" test
(at least for reasonable functions $f$ such as the functions one uses for most practical purposes),
we cannot graph a multivariable function $g(x,y)$ that way,
because $g(x,y)$ assigns a value to every point in its domain,
in this case every point in the plane.
There are various other ways of plotting $g(x,y)$, but they involve
different techniques such as three-dimensional visualization,
contour lines, or other techniques to indicate that the function does
not just have a single value for any given $x$, but rather has a value for
every combination of $x$ and $y$.

I am reminded of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1014401/139123), which is different from yours
but also hinges on the confusion that can occur if one tries to apply
principles of graphing single-variable functions
to a problem concerning a multiple-variable function.
Both single-variable and multiple-variable functions can be related
to the same $x,y$-coordinate plane, but they relate to that plane
in very different ways.

Comment: I do not understand some things here.How does $f(x)f(y) = g(x,y)$ $x$ and $y$ are collinear points on the axis.

Comment: In $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx$, the symbol $x$ is a name for the variable of integration. It is not a point, though sometimes it is helpful to relate values of $x$ to labeled points on the $x$-axis of a graph. The notation $g(x,y)$ in the equations is there merely to remind us that when we set up the double integral, the integrand is a function of _two_ variables instead of just one.

Comment: It is a new function right? you didnt **transform** the single variable functions into one, you created a **new** function, in that form? Also, **the formal reason why we can change is because these are BOUND variables right?** By **definition** we are allowed to change the variables: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Comment: Yes, $g$ is a new function. And yes, it is important that in these integrals, $x$ and $y$ are bound variables.

Comment: Okay, so how does $x^2+ y^2 = r^2$ when converting it into polar?

Comment: There's a general theorem covering changes of variables in multiple integrals, and a formula (derived from that theorem) for the transformation described by $x = r \cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$. We apply that formula. Visualizing $r,\theta$ as polar coordinates can be informative if you can "get" the right visualization, but it's not a necessary part of the mathematics.