# Change of freebound variables in Integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Okay, recently I have been looking at:

$$\int_{R} e^{-x^2} dx$$

It has been bothering me that, we can say that:

$$I = \int_{R} e^{-x^2} dx$$

But also that:

$$I = \int_{R} e^{-y^2} dx$$

then

$$I^2 = \int_{R} \int_{R} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dxdy$$

The problem is now we have made a relation that:

$y = f(x)$ because we are tranforming it into a surface.

If we make the relation that $y = f(x)$ then it is false that:

$$I = \int_{R} e^{-y^2} dx$$ Because now $y = f(x)$ and $dy \ne dx$

How does this work then?

Comment: It should be "But also that ... $\int e^{y^2} dy,$ not ending in $dx$ as you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: just stop thinking that a function is $y=f(x)$. A function is (for a calculus student) a rule that to any "number" $\#$ associates a unique "number" $f(\#)$. The *graph* of a function is the set $\{(x,f(x))\mid x \in \operatorname{dom}f \}$ which coincides with $\{(y,f(y))\mid y \in \operatorname{dom}f \}$.

Furthermore, an integral is *not* $\int_D f(x)\, dx$, but $\int_D f$: it depends on $f$ and on the domain $D$, *not* on the name of the *dummy* integration variable.

Comment: But then how do you convert it into a double integral? what about the $xy$ plane then?

Comment: It is an application of Fubini's theorem:$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-x^2-y^2}\, dx \, dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2}\, dx \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-y^2}\, dy=I^2.$$

Comment: So Fubini's theorem says for **two COMPLETELY unrelated variables** after iteration their the variables become **related?** What?

Comment: You should read carefully Fubini's theorem...

Comment: Okay. Wikipedia is very complicated, do you have another possible source?

Comment: Can you understand that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2}\, dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-y^2}\, dy$ (and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\spadesuit^2}\, d\spadesuit$) are the same thing?

Comment: I can fully understand that. But that only holds if it isnt in the form that $y = f(x)$ that is the **condition** for the above. If you consider though $f(x,y)$ as http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html considers, then you are establishing a relationship between $x$ and $y$

Comment: Ah - I think I see: http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_12/fubini.pdf this is saying that over $d(x, y)$ which is our region, we have the equality. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: NO! you need a **function**, not $y=f(x)$. The $y$ in the second integral is **not** (**not**) the $y$ in $y=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Please do not give up on me. I am trying hard to understand, Ill try again. So you are saying we have two functions, $f(x) =  e^{-x^2}$ and $g(y) = e^{-y^2}$ of which $x$ and $y$ are both independent variables right? Then we combine the integrals? What will the respective axes then be though? Thanks

Comment: More precisely we have a single function, but you can count it twice. There is no axis at all here: no axis at all.

Comment: Yes, a single function. $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ then we sub in $y$ to get the other expression. If we have $h(x,y) = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$ then we have to have a surface-graph, what are the axes then is what i am asking.

Comment: We have a function of two variables, please don't think of functions as if they were surfaces. We have a function $h$ of two variables, why do you care about axes? Why do you need any axis?

Comment: To have a graph of the function?

Comment: If you want to sketch the graph of $h$, you need three orthogonal axes, one for the $x$ variable, one for the $y$ variable, and one for the $h(x,y)$ variable.

Comment: And the $y$ has no relation to $x$ correct? It is independent?

Comment: @anonymous Yes, $x$ and $y$ are **completely independent**.

Comment: @MarkFantini, then so the axes in a plane are unrelated? You have two functions correct?

$$f(t) = e^{-t^2}$$
$$h(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

Then you **define a new function**

$$g(x,t) = e^{-(t^2 + x^2)}$$

So the axes dont have to be related? How does a 3D system work?

Comment: @anonymous Like Siminore said, forget tying $x$ and $y$ to axis and think of them only as variables. Axis don't have to be related.

Comment: @MarkFantini alright. But then can you explain the **geometric** aspect of the integral itself? (of the iterated integral?)?

Comment: @anonymous You *can* think of it as the volume below the graph of $e^{-(t^2+x^2)}$, but that is not a requirement for the computation of the integral.

Comment: @MarkFantini, that was the point. Even to graph, $f(x,t) = e^{-(t^2 + x^2)}$ you first need to graph $f(t)$ or $f(x)$ where they are related to the other variable because of the $xt$ plane.

Comment: @anonymous They are not related!!!!! They are **independent** variables!! If they were related, this would not be a function of two variables, but **one** variable!

Comment: What you are doing is:

let $x = y \implies dx = dy$ Then

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2} \, dy$$

But when you combine it:

$$I = \int_{R}\int_{R} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dxdy$$

This is really:

$$I = \int_{R}\int_{R} e^{-2x^2} (dx)^2$$

Applying $x^2 +  y^2 = r^2$ requires $x$ to be perpendicular to $y$.

Which means it requires one to be the "range part," and one to be the "domain part." Doesn't it?  Due to the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: QUESTION #2

We defined in the beginning,

$$h(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

$$\therefore, h(y) = e^{-y^2}$$

But so $x$ and $y$ are colinear, lie in the same line. $y = x$ is not necessary. But still, when you make this 3D, $x$ and $y$ cannot have different axes can they? So it cannot be a multivariable function?

Comment: We say $g(x,y)$ is a multivariable function because you can vary $x$ without varying $y$, or vary $y$ without varying $x$, or vary both $x$ and $y$. Here $x$ and $y$ merely stand for two numbers you can put inside the parentheses. For example, $g(2,3)=e^{-(2^2+3^2)}=e^{-13},$ but $g(2,5)=e^{-29},$ $g(4,3)=e^{-25},$ and $g(4,5)=e^{-41}.$ If you can visualize a "graph" in three dimensions you can "plot" these four results as four points at various heights above the $x,y$-plane, but if that is not clear to you then _do not visualize any graph at all_. Fubini does not require a graph.